# How to delete old references in Python?

Tags: python, object, del

Let's say I have the following classes

```
class Daddy:
    children=[]

    def addChild(self,aChild):
        self.children.append(aChild)

class Child:
    name = ''
    def __init__(self, aName):
        self.name = aName

aChild = Child('Peter')
aDaddy = Daddy()
aDaddy.addChild(aChild)
print aDaddy.children[0].name
del(aDaddy)
anotherDaddy = Daddy()
print anotherDaddy.children[0].name
```

Daddy() keeps a reference to the object aDaddy, and I get the following output:

```
Peter
Peter
```

Comment: `del object` that's all

Comment: `children` is class level variable. You need to defined it as instance level variable.

Comment: see related question [Static class variables in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/68645/static-class-variables-in-python)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`children` is a class variable (similar to static variables in other languages), so it's shared across all instances of `Daddy` (same with the `name` variable in `Child`).

Initialize it in `__init__` instead:

```
class Daddy:
    def __init__(self):
        self.children = []

    def addChild(self,aChild):
        self.children.append(aChild)
```